# Higher Order Components (HOC) Authentication in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been using React for web development, and I recently decided to learn React Native.

Usually in React, I use higher order components to protect an particular route from users to access it when they are not logged in (authenticated).

However, when it comes to React Native, since a user can not type a path(URL) to access the page like in web, is it necessary to do such a thing?

I am sorry if this is an obvious question. I am really new to mobile development.

Comment: This is a really good question, and I'm sad there isn't a clear answer here. The user could background the app and have their session timed out, but I haven't seen much discussion about using HOC.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this might be something you are looking for

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux